# Is an affine function with offset non-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Definition:** A function $g:\Bbb R^n\ \longrightarrow\Bbb R^m$ is *affine* if it is of the form $$g(x)=Mx+v$$ 
for some matrix $M\in\operatorname{Mat}(n\times m,\Bbb R)$ and vector $v\in \Bbb R^m$.

---

The matrix multiplication with $M$ is **linear**. So if there is no offset provided by $v$, then the affine function itself is also linear.

So let's say $v\neq0$.
Is it then correct to say that the affine function itself (because of $v\neq0$) is now non-linear?

Comment: It could be called a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) but not in the context of linear algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an affine map $g$ with non-zero translation part (i.e $v\neq 0$) is non-linear since $g(0)=v\neq 0$ (a linear map sends $0$ to $0$).